# Using primary key & foreign key to build ltree

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I am pretty new to postgres & especially new to ltree.
Searching the web for ltree brought me to examples where the tree was build by chaining characters. But I want to use the primary key & foreign key.

Therefore I build the following table:

```
create table fragment(
        id serial primary key,
        description text,
        path ltree
    );
create index tree_path_idx on fragment using gist (path);
```

Instead of A.B.G I want to have 1.3.5.
A root in the examples online is added like so:

```
insert into fragment (description, path) values ('A', 'A');
```

Instead of A I want to have the primary key (which I don't know at that moment). Is there a way to do that?

When adding a child I got the same problem:

```
insert into tree (letter, path) values ('B', '0.??');
```

I know the id of the parent but not of the child that I want to append.

Is there a way to do that or am I completey off track?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a trigger which modifies `path` before each insert. For example, using this setup:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fragment;
CREATE TABLE fragment(
    id serial primary key
    , description text
    , path ltree
);
CREATE INDEX tree_path_idx ON fragment USING gist (path);
```

Define the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_on_fragment()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    new.path := new.path ||  new.id::text;
    return new;
END $$;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_on_fragment ON fragment;
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_fragment
BEFORE INSERT ON fragment
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert_on_fragment();
```

Test the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO fragment (description, path) VALUES ('A', '');
SELECT * FROM fragment;
-- | id | description | path |
-- |----+-------------+------|
-- |  1 | A           |    1 |
```

Now insert B under id = 1:

```
INSERT INTO fragment (description, path) VALUES ('B', (SELECT path FROM fragment WHERE id=1));
SELECT * FROM fragment;

-- | id | description | path |
-- |----+-------------+------|
-- |  1 | A           |    1 |
-- |  2 | B           |  1.2 |
```

Insert C under B:

```
INSERT INTO fragment (description, path) VALUES ('C', (SELECT path FROM fragment WHERE description='B'));
SELECT * FROM fragment;

-- | id | description |  path |
-- |----+-------------+-------|
-- |  1 | A           |     1 |
-- |  2 | B           |   1.2 |
-- |  3 | C           | 1.2.3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone checking this in the future, I had the same issue and I figured out a way to do it without triggers and within the same INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO fragment (description, path)
VALUES ('description', text2ltree('1.' || currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('fragment', 'id'))));
```

**Explanation:**

We can get the id of the current insert operation using `currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('fragment', 'id'))`, which we can concatenate as a string with the parent full path `'parent_path' ||` and finally convert it to `ltree` using `text2ltree()`. The id from `currval()` doesn't have to be incremented because it is called during INSERT, so it is already incremented.

One edge case to be aware of is when you insert a node without any parent then you can't just remove the string concatenation `'1.' ||` because the argument for `text2ltree()` must be text while id on its own is an integer. Instead you have concatenate the id with an empty string `'' ||`.

However, I prefer to create this function to get the path and clean up the insert query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_tree_path("table" TEXT, "column" TEXT, parent_path TEXT)
RETURNS LTREE
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NOT (parent_path = '') THEN
        parent_path = parent_path || '.';
    END IF;
    RETURN text2ltree(parent_path || currval(pg_get_serial_sequence("table", "column")));
END;
$$
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
INSERT INTO fragment (description, path)
VALUES ('description', get_tree_path('fragment', 'id', '1.9.32'));
```

If you don't have any parent, then replace the parent_path `'1.9.32'` with empty text `''`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, needs the full parent path for insert, but the updates and deletes are simply cascaded :)

```
create table if not exists tree
(
    -- primary key
    id serial,
    
    -- surrogate key
    path ltree generated always as (coalesce(parent_path::text,'')::ltree || id::text::ltree) stored unique,
    
    -- foreign key
    parent_path ltree, 
    constraint fk_parent
    foreign key(parent_path) 
    references tree(path)
    on delete cascade
    on update cascade,

    -- content
    name text      
);
```